# Translate service in Angular ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization

I am using angular pipe and service created which are working file with html code. But they are not working when i am using it with TS  file.

translate service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TranslateServices {
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  async use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
    return await new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/i18n/${lang || 'en'}.json`;
      this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
          resolve(this.data);
        },
        error => {
          this.data = {};
          resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

translate pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateServices } from '../../../shared/services';
    @Pipe({ name: 'translate', pure: false })
    export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private translate: TranslateServices) { }
      transform(key): any {
        // console.log('this.translate.data[key]', this.translate.data[key]);
        return this.translate.data[key] || key;
      }
    }
```

this works fine in html

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="{{ 'lbl.SearchByCodeOrStatus' | translate }}" class="form-control border-0">
```

but when i use this i all breaks

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
this.translate.get([menuItem.title]).subscribe(translations => {
   menuItem.title: translations[menuItem.title]
});
```

Comment: You present a `TranslateServices` class, but then the issue relates to a different class, `TranslateService`. Furthermore, the small snippet exemplifying your issue is incomplete. Please expand your question

Answer (score 0):

- first make a translate service or helper.
- then make the pipe that uses that service to output data.

to use the translator in the template file use the pipe function.
to use it inside the ts file use the service or helper function.

pipe's purpose is not to be used inside the ts file.

Comment: I found that i can only use pipe in html its for that use only. but since i have made a service i should be able to get the expected output. but i am not able to get it...

i have already mentioned the service i have made on the top